# Why isn't a widget on my flask app showing up on EC2 instance when it does on local?

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, bokeh

I'm trying to deploy a flask app on an aws EC2 instance using elastic beanstalk. The flask app serves up a Bokeh widget that is read into a Jinja2 template.

Running on my local machine, I run the flask app with app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000). I create a server document for the widget at 'http://localhost:5006/widget'. When I open http://localhost:8000 the page renders with the widget. I can also open localhost:5006/widget and I will see the widget by itself.

Now when I go and deploy this on elastic beanstalk, I change the widget's server document to ':5006/widget' and run the app at host=. If I open ':5006/widget' in the browser it will again show me my widget which interacts as it should. However, when I go to  it will show a page that renders all the html, but the widget is not visible. Further, when I interact with the page at  which modifies the widget, I can go over to :5006/widget and the changes will show up on the widget. It seems that the widget works like it should and can interact with the web page, but I just can't figure out why the widget won't show on the main page.

I've opened inbound ports for tcp on 5006 and 8000 and no errors show up in the console. What could be blocking the widget from showing?

Edit: Trying to clarify how the app is embedded:

```
doc = bokeh.plotting.curdoc()
def createWidget(doc):
    p = figure(...)
    doc.add_root(p)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bkapp_page():
    widget = server_document('<ec2-ip>:5006/widget')
    return render_template("index.html", widget=widget, template="Flask")

def bk_worker():
    server = Server({'/widget': createWidget, io_loop=IOLoop(), allow_websocket_origin=["*"])
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.start()

from threading import Thread
thread = Thread(target=bk_worker)
thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=<ec2-ip>, port=5000)
```

Then in index.html I have the {{widget | safe }} line. Running on local I use server_document('http://localhost:5006/widget') and app.run(host=0.0.0.0, port=5000).

Edit: As bigreddot pointed out, the source must use https if the url for the page uses https.

Comment: Are there any messages in the browser JS console? Are there any bokeh server log errors? Did you set `--allow-websocket-orgin` to allow connections originating from your embedding page?

Comment: No messages in the JS console, set to Verbose. No bokeh server log errors I can see either (in ec2 this would be placed under the Logs correct?) I set --allow-websocket-origin="*" to allow all. I can see the widget on the <ec2-ip> and when I interact on the page the changes manifest, it's just not showing on the main page and I can't see a single trace indicating why it isn't.

Comment: Please update your question with detail about how you are embedding the Bokeh server content in your Flask page

Comment: Updated to show how it's embedded

Comment: I don't really see anything amiss, I am afraid I am not sure what else to suggest at this point. Is the actual expected script making it in to the rendered template?

Comment: On local when I inspect the source it will show several layers of bk-root ending with <canvas class=bk bk-canvas. However on ec2 it will just say the <script src=IP...autoload.js. So somehow the instructions to load from that ip resource seem to not be propagating like they should. Any ideas at all?

Comment: Does the network pane in the browser dev tools show that that script is actually able to be fetched/loaded? Maybe there is a problem at that step.

Comment: The network pane does indicate a problem. On local it shows a bunch of resources associated with the server_document script being loaded. On ec2 it doesn't even show them attempting to fetch/load. Bokeh...min.js and bokeh-widgets...min.js are both there with a 200, but none of the resources associated with the plot are. No errors or 400s. Do you have any thoughts on what could be going on/a troubleshooting approach?

Comment: Is the script URL an http location, but the ec2 page an https location? Browsers will not execute scripts from insecure (http) locations on secure (https) pages

Comment: I think this is the issue!

Comment: I'm glad to hear, can you post and self-accept an answer? (Better for the project to have fewer unanswered questions lingering)